# How do I globally register a Liquid filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I created a custom Liquid filter

```
module LinkFilter
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

 def link(input,source)
  link_to input,source
 end
end
```

and placed it in `app/filters/LinkFilter.rb`

How do I globally register the filter? According the Liquid documentation, adding this line at the end of the above file would register it globally:

```
Liquid::Template.register_filter(LinkFilter)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Am I placing the filter in the wrong location or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the filter in the `lib` directory instead. The one in the application root, not the `app/lib` one (if you have one).